# unwanted "!" marks in php html emails

Tags: php, email

I use php default mail function to send html e-mails.
My code:

```
//SENDMAIL

// multiple recipients
$to  = ''. $email .'' . ', '; // note the comma
$to .= 'adress@domain.com';


// subject
$subject = 'subject';

// message
$message = '
<html>
<head>
<title>Email</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1257">
<style type="text/css">
body,td,th {
 font-family: Verdana;
 font-size: 12px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body bgcolor="#FFFFFF" leftmargin="0" topmargin="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0">
html table data ...... in html syntax
';

if(($b1 == "true" || $b2 == "true" || $b3 == "true" || $b4 == "true" || $b5 == "true" || $b6 == "true" || $b7 == "true" || $b8 == "true" || $b9 == "true" || $b10 == "true" || $b11 == "true" || $b12 == "true" || $b13 == "true" || $b14 == "true" || $b15 == "true" || $b16 == "true") && $enb == "true")
{
 $message .= 'link1<br>
 ';
}
if(($b1 == "true" || $b2 == "true" || $b3 == "true" || $b4 == "true" || $b5 == "true" || $b6 == "true" || $b7 == "true" || $b8 == "true" || $b9 == "true" || $b10 == "true" || $b11 == "true" || $b12 == "true" || $b13 == "true" || $b14 == "true" || $b15 == "true" || $b16 == "true") && $nlb == "true")
{
 $message .= 'link2<br> 
 ';
}
$message .='html body continued in html syntax
$message .= '</html>';

// To send HTML mail, the Content-type header must be set
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' . "\r\n";

// Additional headers
$headers .= 'To: ' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: Sender <no-reply@domain.com>' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Cc: ' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Bcc: ' . "\r\n";

// Mail it
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

When the message is sent sometimes, not always there appears mystical ! marks in the middle of text.
For instance :
"thank you f!or your email"
or
"Ki!d regards," and cetra.
It appears to be no pattern in this, so I wanted to ask, if this is a common mistake in php mail, and how to overcome it?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you show the generated source code of such a sentence?

Comment: wanna try Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1 instead of utf8 ?   Are you actually encoding it as utf8 ?

Comment: YIKES!  What's with the string booleans?  instead of `$b1 == "true"`, couldn't you just set `$b1 = true` earlier in the code and then check `if ($b1)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a limit for maximum chars allowed in each line of an email(998), I think it depends on it.
Use wordwrap to avoid these long lines.

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing

> meta http-equiv="Content-Type"
>   content="text/html;
>   charset=windows-1257"

and the headers

> ```
> Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8
> ```

Go for utf-8 and make sure it is utf-8 you're actually sending by 
using http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding.php
mb_convert_encoding to convert to utf-8.

```
mail($to, $subject, mb_convert_encoding( $message, "UTF-8"), $headers);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use http://php.net/wordwrap to limit your lines to 80 characters and append an equal sign (`=`) at the end of wrapped lines.

Answer (score 0):

I just experienced the same thing with VB Script on an ASP page. The solution is the same though: break up the HTML line in the VB using `vbNewLine`.